# Working with LCD Optrex F-51684 without datasheet

Tags: automotive, display

I have a display from Panasonic car stereo (Toyota Corolla), but can't determine how to work it. It's called Optrex F-51684, and there is no datasheet for that LCD. Is it possible to find how to work with it without datasheet? This is screenshot of the connector pins from main board:
[image: connector]

So it has a serial interface, i can select a chip here (CS1 and CS2), but also there is an unknown pin LCD-DET.

I thought it has S1D15605 (like nearest Optrex LCD-s) controller but pins seem different. Also there is chip on the module, marked as EF766102 B01 R ,without any information about it on the internet. Same time it has a name IC2 so it should be second chip, but there is no sign of IC1. Can it be hidden somehow?

Comment: It's possibly a reset pin.

Comment: There is also LCD-RST on the other side, two reset pins?

Comment: I make it a rule never to design with anything that doesn't have a recognizable data sheet so it's anyone's guess.

Comment: Look at the chips on the LCD module, see if you can identify the LCD controller chip. It may be possible to get a datasheet for that chip, in which case you are 90% of the way there.

Comment: I've added additional information to the post about chips.

Comment: if it isn't broken you could add a logic analyser and/or a 'scope to the circuit while it's plugged in to the car, record your measurements and reverse-engineer it from there

Comment: @FMashiro yes, eventually I did that, it was ST7565, quite common LCD controlller

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to find how to work with it without datasheet?

Absolutely possible, just like finding a needle in a haystack is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have the datasheet but it says that the controller chip is S1D15605. I downloaded the datasheet 16 years ago. How can I upload it?

Comment: Welcome to SE/EE! You cannot. This is a Q&A site, not a forum or something else. Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. Anyway, the question was posted more than 4 years ago.

Comment: If you can post it on web you can post a link here. If not you could send it to me and I can do so. If doing that please also send link to this question. My email address is in my profile